# How to schedule Oozie coordinator cron to launch at same time in local timezone accounting for daylight savings

Tags: oozie, dst, oozie-coordinator

I have an Oozie coordinator setup with the following information:

`frequency="00 09 * * *" timezone="America/New_York"`

Currently we are UTC-4 (EDT), hence if I want the job to run at 5am I have to set the cron to run at 00 09 * * *.

However when we switch back to UTC-5 (EST) from daylight savings, will I need to go back and edit to `00 10 * * *`? I want the job to always run at 5am Eastern (EST/EDT), regardless of DST.

I have read through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37149272/10316759) which I think is similar as well as the JIRA solution but it didn't seem to answer my question. The JIRA response seems to indicate this is fixed, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Workaround : define a Coordinator that runs from (now) to (next date-time for DST switch), and another one that will take over until the next switch, etc. Requires manual submission twice a year (which can be scripted if you think that's worth it)

Comment: _"JIRA ... indicates this is fixed"_ > the JIRA header states that the "fix" **will** ship with V5.1 -- current Apache version is 5.0, not sure what it is in the Horton/Cloudera/Amazon/etc distros.

Comment: And hopefully it will be documented in V5.2 or 5.3 (if we are lucky)